# jQuery: display divs with numbers ranging from/to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to display divs ranging from/to numbers using a select dropdown list.

I have created this jsfiddle to explain the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/chd836b8/2/

basically, each div has a `data-price=""` and they have different values in them as you can see in the jsfiddle!

i need to select the price rang from the `dropdown list` and display the divs accordingly. so far I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `data` attributes to the `option` elements that determine the min/max price for that selection:

```
<select id="priceRange" style="width:101px; height:49px; background:#eeeeee; border-radius:8px;">
    <option data-price-min="0" data-price-max="49">Under 50</option>
    <option data-price-min="50" data-price-max="100">50 - 100</option>
    <option data-price-min="100" data-price-max="250">100 - 250</option>
    <option data-price-min="250" data-price-max="500">250 - 500</option>
    <option data-price-min="500" data-price-max="1000">500 - 1000</option>
    <option data-price-min="1000" data-price-max="9999">Over 1000</option>
</select>
```

Then in JS, you can read those attributes when the `select` is changed, and find the relevant `.drag` elements whose `data-price` falls between those extents:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var min = $option.data('price-min');
    var max = $option.data('price-max');
    $('.drag').hide().filter(function() {
        var price = $(this).data('price');
        return price >= min && price <= max;
    }).show();
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/chd836b8/4/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I need to know why your code doesn't work when I change the jquery library to 1.6.1. ... Could you please advise on this?

Comment: @H.HISTORY Initial jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chd836b8/ appear to utilize jQuery `1.8.3` ? Why would version `1.6.1` be used, instead of most recently updated version ?

Comment: I know but this is part of a bigger project and the entire older codes rely on the older jQuery!

Comment: It's because `on` was introduced in 1.7. You really should upgrade from 1.6.1 though, as it's *very* out of date. To fix the problem, change `.on('change',` to `.change(`. See this fiddle using 1.6.4: http://jsfiddle.net/chd836b8/7/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add `data-min` and `data-max` to your options:

```
<select id="priceRange">
<option data-min="0" data-max="49">Under 50</option>
<option data-min="50" data-max="100">50 - 100</option>
<option data-min="100" data-max="250">100 - 250</option>
<option data-min="250" data-max="500">250 - 500</option>
<option data-min="500" data-max="1000">500 - 1000</option>
<option data-max="1000">Over 1000</option>
```

This will allow you to limit the visible divs later on.

Next you need to perform a

```
$(".drag").each(function(){
     var price = $(this).data('price');
     //and then check if it fits between min and max to show it
});
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't really make sense! would you mind elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `data-*` attribute to `option` elements as array of minimum , maximum values , or range to filter `.drag` elements

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var range = $(this.selectedOptions[0]).data("range")
    $(".drag").hide().filter(function(i, el) {
      var n = $(this).data().price;
      return !!range[1] ? n >= range[0] && n <= range[1] : n >= range[0]
    }).show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="priceRange" style="width:101px; height:49px; background:#eeeeee; border-radius:8px;">
  <option data-range='[0, 50]'>Under 50</option>
  <option data-range='[50, 100]'>50 - 100</option>
  <option data-range='[100, 250]'>100 - 250</option>
  <option data-range='[250, 500]'>250 - 500</option>
  <option data-range='[500, 1000]'>500 - 1000</option>
  <option data-range='[1000]'>Over 1000</option>
</select>



<div data-price="2" class="drag">2</div>
<div data-price="2" class="drag">2</div>
<div data-price="4" class="drag">4</div>
<div data-price="7" class="drag">7</div>
<div data-price="20" class="drag">20</div>
<div data-price="40" class="drag">40</div>
<div data-price="100" class="drag">100</div>
<div data-price="200" class="drag">200</div>
<div data-price="200" class="drag">200</div>
<div data-price="500" class="drag">500</div>
<div data-price="1000" class="drag">1000</div>
<div data-price="1100" class="drag">1100</div>
<div data-price="2000" class="drag">2000</div>
<div data-price="2000" class="drag">2000</div>
<div data-price="3000" class="drag">3000</div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle utilizing jQuery version 1.6.4 with `.live` substituted for `.on` http://jsfiddle.net/chd836b8/6/